# How can i get second span value by clicking on break down link?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<div class="priceStruct" id="priceStruct">
     <h3>Pallet Cost Structure</h3>

              <?php $i=1;
              foreach($price_structure as  $price_structure_list) {
                  $palletDetails  = $price_structure_list['min']." - ".$price_structure_list['max'];
              ?>
              <div class="display_content" id="price<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <span class="first price" id="first<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo $palletDetails." Pallets";?></span>
                <span class="second price" id="second<?php echo $i; ?>">£<?php echo $price_structure_list['price'];?></span>
                <span class="third price"><a href="#" class="breakDown" >Click Here for Break Down</a></span>
              </div>

              <?php $i++; } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: just onlcik function and use $('.second price').text();

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `Class` should be `second_price` instead of `second price`.
Dont forget to include jQuery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

$(function(){
    $(".breakDown").click(function(){         
            spanValue  = $('.second_price').text();   
            alert(spanValue);// just to check     

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Add this to your `a` tag:

```
onclick="alert($('#second<?php echo $i; ?>').text());"
```

So that it will result in:

```
<a href="#" class="breakDown" onclick="alert($('#second<?php echo $i; ?>').text());">Click Here for Break Down</a>
```

**Solution 2:**

You can also use jQuery's `parent` and `siblings` to find the correct span tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.breakDown').click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().siblings('.second').text());
    });
});
```

The disadvantage of solution 2 is that you'll run in problems when the structure of your HTML code is changed (the `a` tag is no longer not a child of `span` etc.)